# AmSynth 1.5.1 with jack and alsa (JACK init failed: error: could not open ALSA MIDI interface)

Tags: audio, jack

I built and compiled amSynth 1.5.1 from source. I then started qjackctl and ran `amsynth` from command line, but it produced the following error.

```
 JACK init failed:
 error: could not open ALSA MIDI interface
```

However, I had amSynth 1.3.2 (the one in the Mint 17 repositories) running perfectly fine.
What caused this/how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discovery: the reason this happened is because I did not **configure** amsynth to be built with JACK and ALSA support when compiling.

Look at the output of running `./configure`:

```
| Build with ALSA support............................... : no
| Build with JACK support............................... : no
```

Two steps to fix:

1. Make sure the following packages are installed: `libjack-jackd2-dev` `libasound2-dev`
2. Go back to the amsynth-1.5.1 directory and run `sudo ./configure --with-alsa --with-jack` followed by the usual `sudo make` and `sudo make install`

Comment: delete you second post and add that to the first one.

Comment: No as then people don't know whether it's answered or not

Comment: After installing `amsynth` from the kxstudio repositories, I had the same issue. Your answer put me on the path of the solution, thanks!